# Como atualizar um CRUD com Scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

Tenho um sistema com Ruby e foi criado um CRUD via Scaffold e eu gostaria de adicionar alguns campos novos.

Poŕem o que eu achei na internet foi utilizando o seguinte comando.

```
rails generate migration add_preco_to_produtos preco:decimal
```

Porém este comando somente atualizará o banco de dados, e eu gostaria de atualizar o CRUD inteiro. Existe algum comando que possa me auxiliar?

Answer (score 2):

Essa sua dúvida é muito comum para quem está começando com Rails, eu já tive o mesmo questionamento.

O Scaffold é um recurso que serve somente para iniciar um CRUD básico, você usa bastante no começo, mas depois vai começar a perceber que ele é simples demais para a maioria dos casos.

Ele não atualiza o código no caso de mudanças por um bom motivo, ou ele reescreveria tudo e vc perderia tudo que alterou ou seria uma ferramenta complexa para conseguir "entender" o que foi alterado e o que foi gerado inicialmente.

Então a resposta simples é: Vc terá que atualizar na mão seu código.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá o scaffold gera todas as partes necessárias para um crud,caso queira adicionar mais campos ou modificar um gerado você terá que alterar manualmente e caso precise alterar o banco você pode gerar uma migration para isso.

```
rails g migration add_age_to_users age:int
```

O comando acima gera uma migration para adicionar o campo age na tabela users.

Não esqueça de alterar as views e controlers para o campo aparecer e seja gravado.